# How to get direction from 2 positions in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, direction

Could somebody help me? I am trying to get the direction value in worldSpace based on 2 given positions in Maya. How can I do that in python?
Is it not just subtracting the 2 positions?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's the difference of the two position vectors, with pymel it can look like this:

```
import pymel.core as pm    
v = pm.PyNode("locator2").translate.get() - pm.PyNode("locator1").translate.get()
```

Open Maya version:

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
v = om.MVector([1,2,3]) - om.MVector([4,5,6])
```